# How to disable a YUI MenuBarItem from markup

Tags: javascript, html, css, yui

I prefer creating my nav menus from markup (rather than Javascript), like in [this example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/topnavfrommarkup.html). Is it possible to create menus and/or menu items from markup which are disabled? I see how to use Javascript to do this (use the [`disabled` config property](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/#mitemconfigref)), but I'm looking for some way to encode this information in markup - perhaps there's a CSS class to use? Or am I out of luck here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it was bugged but shot down.

http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/ticket/2527643

Comment: I'd have to disagree with kloots on that one, and agree with lee. Anyway the [example](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/attachment/2527643/example.html) linked from your link was good enough for me. Thanks!